# Função que faça a conversão dessa string para um json

Tags: javascript, json, regex, conversão, parse

Tenho uma `string` com o seguinte formato:

```
"a=123 b="ABC" c="Olá Mundo!""
```

preciso criar uma função que transforme essa string neste json:

```
{
    a : 123,
    b : "ABC",
    c : "Olá Mundo!"
}
```

Creio que tenha um pouco de expressão regular e um split(), mas não sei quase nada de RegEx.

Estava desenvolvendo essa função, mas não obtive muito sucesso.

```js
    function strToJson(str) {
        var json = {};
        var str_split = str.split(" ");
        var str_split_value = [];

        for (var i in str_split) {
            str_split_value = str_split[i].split("=");
            json[str_split_value[0]] = str_split_value[1];
        }

        return json;
    }

    console.log(strToJson('a=123 b="ABC" c="Olá Mundo!"'));
```

Comment: Se tem algo que tentou, algum começo de código?Ou só o problema em si?

Comment: Minha lógica seria fazer um split() na string separando pelos espaços, mas essa lógica não dá muito certo no item c.

Comment: Então, mas começa algo...e vê onde emperra, dai edita a pergunta e bota seu código...Num leva a mal, mai daí vai ter mais respostas...E vão te ajudar a solucionar...

Comment: [Chamar uma função PHP quando usuário entra na página, algum exemplo?](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/134283/45854)

Comment: Embora você tenha recebido uma resposta e esteja satisfeito com ela, este tipo de operação parece fundamentalmente problemática ao usar um formato de dados sem especificação completa. Só para citar um exemplo, o que aconteceria se houvessem aspas dentro de um texto? Antes de colocar um código desses em produção, sempre verifique se não é possível já escrever os dados num formato consistente como o próprio JSON.

Comment: Claro que não vou por isso em produção, é que sou muito curioso, e muitas das perguntas que faço por aqui é somente para conhecimento.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tudo é mais fácil com REGEX.

```
([a-zA-Z_]\w*?)=(\d+|"[^"]*")( |$)
```

#### Explicação

`([a-zA-Z_]\w*?)`

Parte do nome da variável - Grupo 1

- `[a-zA-Z_]` = vai garantir que inicie com uma letra ou *underline*
- `\w*?` = permite que tenha mais letras números e *underline*

`(\d+|"[^"]*")`

Parte do conteúdo - Grupo 2

- `\d+` = deve capturar numeros
- `|` = **OU** quer disser que se o anterior falhar tenta o próximo
- `"[^"]*"` = Deve capturar um <kbd>"</kbd> qualquer coisa que não <kbd>"</kbd> e por fim uma <kbd>"</kbd> - uma string

Parte do termino - Grupo 3 (não útil para uso)

- `( |$)` - Indica que o conteudo termina **OU** com  (espaço) **OU** (Termino de sentença, fim do conteúdo)

#### Uso

```
'a=123 b="ABC" c="Olá Mundo!"'.match(/([a-zA-Z_]\w*?)=(\d+|"[^"]*")( |$)/g)
```

Veja funcionando em [REGEX101](https://regex101.com/r/kC9uN1/1)

Answer (score 5):

```
var s = 'a=123 b="ABC" c="Olá Mundo!"';

var obj = {},
    parcial = '',
    inString = false,
    isProp = true,
    conteudo = '',
    prop = '';
for (i = 0; i < s.length; i++) { 
    var atual = s[i];

    if(atual=='"'){
        inString = !inString;
    }

    if((atual==' ')&&(!inString)){
        isProp=true;
        parcial='';
        obj[prop]=conteudo;
        continue;
    }
    if(atual == '='){
        isProp=false;
        parcial='';
        continue;
    }

    parcial += atual;
    if(isProp){
        prop=parcial;
    } else {
        conteudo=parcial;
    }

    if(i==s.length-1){
        obj[prop]=conteudo;
    }

    console.log('Atual: "'+atual+'"; Parcial: "'+parcial+'"; Prop:"'+prop+'"; Conteudo:"'+conteudo+'";');

}

console.log(obj);
```

Comment: Extamente o que eu precisava! Só preciso entender a lógica do código...

Answer (score 3):

Nenhum split() ou expressão regular simples vai fazer o que você quer. Você precisa desenvolver um mini-interpretador, com máquina de estado. Algo nesse estilo (em pseudocódigo):

```
estado = 0;
nome = "";
valor = "";

// sentinela para terminar o parse dentro do loop
str += " ";

for (i = 0; i < str.length(); ++i) {
    // interpreta caractere por caractere
    c = str[i];
    if (estado === 0) {
        // estado: inicial
        c é espaço -> ignora
        c é letra -> estado := 1
                      nome := c
        c de outro tipo -> erro! 
    } else if (estado === 1) {
        // estado: acumulando nome 
        c é letra, número ou _ -> nome += c
        c é "=" -> estado := 2
        c é outro tipo -> erro!
    } else if (estado === 2) {
        // estado: = encontrado
        c é número -> valor := c
                      estado := 3
        c é aspa -> valor := c
                    estado := 4
        c é espaço -> ignora
        c é outra coisa -> erro! 
    } else if (estado === 3) {
        // estado: acumulando valor inteiro
        c é número -> valor += c
        c é espaço -> grava tupla (nome, parseInt(valor))
                      estado := 0
        c é outra coisa -> erro!
    } else if (estado === 4) {
        // estado: acumulando string 
        c é aspa -> grava tupla (nome, valor)
                    estado := 0
        c é qualquer outro caractere -> valor += c
    }
}
```