# Chamar função PHP quando entrar na página

Tags: php

Chamar uma função PHP quando usuário entra na página, algum exemplo?

Comment: O que tentou fazer, e o que não deu certo?

Comment: @Alisson Que Deus tenha misericórdia de ti.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basicamente assim:
Chamo a função quando a página é requisitada.

```
<?php
    myFunction();
    function myFunction() 
    {
        echo "Executou aqui!";
    }
```